# saving a multiline string as the only element in a list in python

Tags: python, string, tuples, multiline

Im trying to print a multiline string from a list.

when using a tuple instead of a list, the result is exactly what I want

```
test = ("""
11111
22222
33333
""")

print(test)
>>>
11111
22222
33333
```

it prints in multiple lines. Now I want the same result, except using a **list** instead of a tuple, the problem is it prints everything out in one single line:

```
test = ["""
11111
22222
33333
"""]

print(test)
>>>['\n11111\n22222\n33333\n']
```

I want it to print out like in the tuple example. Sorry for the dumb question

Answer (score 0):

```
test = ("""
11111
22222
33333
""")
```

is not a tuple. It's a `str`.

```
>>> type(test)
<class 'str'>
```

The following forms a tuple; notice the trailing `,`, which makes it a 1-element tuple.

```
>>> test = ("""
... 11111
... 22222
... 33333
... """, )
>>> type(test)
<class 'tuple'>
>>> print(test)
('\n11111\n22222\n33333\n',)
```

Both the (actual) tuple and the list print the same way, by displaying the `repr()` (`.__repr__()`) of each element in the sequence.

If you'd like to print out the `str()` representation of each element, iterate over the list or tuple and call `print()` on each element.

```
>>> test = ["""
... 11111
... 22222
... 33333
... """]
>>> for i in test: print(i)
... 

11111
22222
33333
```